# Why does a comparison of identical dict values in python 3.5.2 returns False?

Tags: python, json, zip

In order to use the example you need to create the following json file (`test.json`):

```
{
  "/apps/media/efel_data/efel_gui/results/305933/20180515094131/u_res": {
    "step_700.0": {
      "stimuli": [
        {"delay": 620.0, "amp": 700.0, "duration": 1000.0, "totduration": 1300.0},
        {"delay": 0.0, "amp": 0.0, "duration": 1300.0, "totduration": 1300.0}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and to create a zip file containing this single file (just for demonstration purposes)

```
ls | zip -@ files.zip
```

Supposing both files are in a folder `temp` run the following code:

```
import zipfile
import json

z = zipfile.ZipFile("temp/files.zip")
with z.open('test.json') as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
with open('temp/test.json') as f:
    expected = json.loads(f.read())
print(data.values())
print(expected.values())
print(data.values()==expected.values())
```

Now, I need to compare the *values* of the dict (as the first key can be different in the real code usage). However, the output of the code (python 3.5.2) indicates that the identical values are not identical:

```
dict_values([{'step_700.0': {'stimuli': [{'totduration': 1300.0, 'amp': 700.0, 'delay': 620.0, 'duration': 1000.0}, {'totduration': 1300.0, 'amp': 0.0, 'delay': 0.0, 'duration': 1300.0}]}}])
dict_values([{'step_700.0': {'stimuli': [{'totduration': 1300.0, 'amp': 700.0, 'delay': 620.0, 'duration': 1000.0}, {'totduration': 1300.0, 'amp': 0.0, 'delay': 0.0, 'duration': 1300.0}]}}])
False
```

Any explanation what is going on, and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You've got a lot of floats, so maybe it's float imprecision?

Comment: At least it worked with python 2 without issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your 2 dict are identical. This can be confirmed if you convert your `dict.values()` to `list()` for example:

```
print(list(data.values()) == list(expected.values()))
```

> True

I think the problem is in the way python *compares* `dict.values()`. The funny thing is that even `items()` work correctly:

```
print(data.items() == expected.items())
```

> True

You mentioned you are not interested in keys, but `keys()` comparison also returns True. items may also be out of the question but it's strange that it doesn't fail as in the values comparison. Anyway as a work around I would suggest converting to a list if it's not too much overhead. If there is I am not sure how you could resolve it, though.